# How enzyme testing the render

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

How write a test for checking render element or not? For example, component like this, which render depends on existing list of cards:

```
class ButtonMore extends Component {
  render() {
    if (!this.props.listCards.length) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.onClick} className="buttons button-more">
        More
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

How would check render depends to props?

```
function setup() {
  const props = {
    listCards: [1, 2]
  };
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ButtonMore {...props} />
    </Provider>
  );
  return {
    props,
    wrapper
  };
}

describe("ButtonMore component", () => {
  const { wrapper } = setup();
  it("should render button if cards length more then 0", () => {
    expect(wrapper.prop("listCards").length).toBe(2); // that's ok
    expect(wrapper.find("button").length).toBe(1); // received 0, not 1
  });
});
```

Unfortunately, i don't finded solution in the enzyme documentation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: "!this.props.listCards.length" checks only that listCards has the property length. You have to ensure that listCards is an array and that the length is more than 0.

Now ensure that your wrapper contains the right data: you can do it with console.log(wrapper.debug());

At the end.. If you don't need the store you can even not use the Provider. Render just ButtonMore and pass onClick and listCards as props.